# Exact meaning of персоналия

Tags: значения

I sometimes consult the site Советская Россия - Свод персоналий at http://www.proza.ru/avtor/igorjan.  But I cannot find персоналия in any dictionary.  What is its exact meaning?  Is it an equivalent of 'persons' or 'personnel', or more like 'personalities' in English?

Answer (score 2):

The word **персоналия** means collection of information about a person:

> ПЕРСОНА́ЛИЯ -и; ж. [от лат. personalis - личный]. Материалы (литература, фотографии, документы и т.п.), посвящённые жизни какого-л. известного человека. *[Большой толковый словарь русского языка]*
>
> Персона́лия. Ж. Раздел в энциклопедии, статья в юбилейном сборнике и т.п., содержащие библиографические данные о ком-либо (обычно ученом, писателе, политическом деятеле и т.п.).
> *[Толковый словарь Ефремовой]*

It is borrowed from Latin, where *personalia* is neuter plural of *persōnālis* - personal.

It is funny that in Russian the word *персоналия* is singular and can form a plural itself - *персоналии*, which means "collection of personalia".

The word персоналия is not a synonym for a персона or персонал. In fact the word *personalia* is also present in English, where it means "personal belongings" or "biographical data, personal reminiscences, or the like".

Comment: Russian National Corpus shows only plural usage of the word. And many journalists use it as a synonym for "person" which is incorrect.

Comment: Here is an article about modern usage of word персоналия: [Фигурант и персоналия в языке и речи](http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200200204) here the персоналия is also treated as "личное дело".

Comment: For an exact meaning of any russian word, I recommend slovari.yandex.ru

Comment: @user31264 +1 to your comment. In fact even Wikipedia has an article on [персоналия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F) with a compilation of meanings from different dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

It is *person/personality bio/info* ([Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F)) but often it is incorrectly used for *person* ([Wikireality](http://www.wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Answer (score -1):

The word of *персоналия* isn't used in single form, only in plural as *персоналии*. The single form is *персона*. Yes, it is a person in context of its biography descrption.

Comment: No, персона is not a single form for персоналии. It is different word.

Comment: No, the same, there no word of персоналия. Even it is contained in dictionary...